# Histogram Equalization yielding unexpected results

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, histogram, contrast

I have a series of images with decreasing brightness that I would like to try to correct with histogram equalization. I applied `histeq` to some test data to learn how the function works

```
% Image that I would like to apply histogram equalization to
C = gallery('wilk',21);
figure, imagesc(C)

E = histeq(C);
figure, imagesc(E);
```

However, when I look at the output of `histeq`, I get a result that only has two unique values: `0.873` and `1.000`. How come the output doesn't span the whole range of the input? I would expect there to be more than two unique values in the output.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just do `imhist`? It accepts an image and it outputs a histogram in a figure. Also, what does `unique(C)` return after you histogram equalize?

Comment: Please show your histogram equalization code.  In the meantime, did you try `histeq`?

Comment: Ah.  I just noticed what the input is now.  It's not working because the input you are specifying is crap for histogram equalization.  The dynamic range and the distribution of intensities is very small, which will blow up the range once you "normalize" it. Recommend you read up on how histogram equalization works before using it. Try this on an actual image before proceeding further.  For example, use the Image Processing Toolbox image: `C = imread('pout.tif');`.

Comment: Histogram equalization is primarily for enhancing images.  That's why `histeq` is part of the image processing toolbox.  The purpose of histogram equalization is to make the probability distribution function of the signal (ideally) equiprobable.  This has absolutely no meaning for computational signals, but for image contrast, having an image with all intensities equiprobable (usually) results in a better enhanced image.  `tl;dr`: Don't use histogram equalization on anything but actual images.

Comment: btw, `imhist` doesn't return a blank output.  If you look at intensity 1, all of the intensities are mapped to that intensity after normalization.  Again, you are using bad inputs.

Comment: Try using [`clim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html) instead.  Histogram equalization is overkill for your purposes.

Comment: Again, you are using bad inputs. You are probably saving the heat maps to disk, then using GIMP you are equalizing the actual image data from that saved heat map that is representative of that signal, **not the actual signal itself**. As I keep telling you time and time again, **you are using bad inputs**. This will be my last message.

Comment: @Masi Normalize `C` before passing it to `histeq`: `histeq(mat2gray(C))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation for `histeq`, if the input is of type `double` or `single` it is expected to be in the range: `[0, 1]`.

> Intensity values in the appropriate range: [0, 1] for images of class double, [0, 255] for images of class uint8, and [0, 65535] for images of class uint16.

Your data is not normalized and is of type `double`,

```
whos C

%  Name       Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes
%
%  C         21x21             3528  double    

[min(C(:)), max(C(:))]
%   0   10
```

You will need to normalized it first. You can use `mat2gray` to do this:

```
E = histeq(mat2gray(C));
```

[image]

Comment: You're probably plotting with `imshow`. `imshow` makes the figures the actual size (in pixels) so they will be small because they are 21 x 21. Also it defaults to a `gray` colormap. Use `imagesc`.

Comment: @Masi What you just wrote doesn't make much sense to me. It's hard to say what the appropriate thing to do with your data is since we can't see it. Maybe ask a new question that is image processing specific showing what you've tried to do to correct your data? Also include the data itself and show the expected output. This question was simply regarding your mis-use of `histeq`

Comment: How can you decide which `hgram` to apply specific Matrix in `histeq(Matrix)`? Etc if `size(Matrix)` is `1     2093809`. I do not like to get flat histograms here. - - To generate `n=size(pTFD,2); hgram = ones(1,n)*prod(size(pTFD))/n;` is resource-heavy.

Comment: @Masi I can't understand your question. Histogram equalization isn't the same as computing a histogram...

Comment: @Masi The output of `histeq` will always be the size of the input. You must be passing it a 1D image

Comment: What about hgram's effect on `histeq`?

Comment: @Masi It allows you to specify an expected distribution. So you could in theory match two images using something like: `histeq(im2, hist(im1))`